# Get value from dynamic list of object using javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Seeking the below result with dynamic list of object using javascript. Defined approach getting me undefined index of value.

Javascript Code

```js
var obj = {};
var obj_ = {
  "clist_1": "abc",
  "clist_2": "def",
  "branch_1": "efg"
}
for (let key in obj_) {
  if (key.includes("clist_")) {
    let num = key.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
    obj[num] = obj_.key;
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

Desired Result

```
{
  "1": "abc",
  "2": "def"
}
```

Comment: `obj_[key];` instead of `obj_.key;` - I can't believe this isn't a duplicate of about 100 questions

Comment: your SO search foo is superior to mine @RobinZigmond

Comment: @JaromandaX I confess I used Google, never tried using SO's own search :) As you say there are loads I could have marked this as a dupe of

Comment: ahh @RobinZigmond - that is indeed very wise

Comment: @JaromandaX It might be is duplicate which i have posted here but sometime it happening with person was not be able to search exact indenfied thing which he has needed. Thankyou for you support its really helpful for me

Comment: Oh, @QueryMaster - I'm with you, I could not find the duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). You need to do `obj_[key]` and not `obj_.key`.

```js
var obj = {};
var obj_ = {
  "clist_1": "abc",
  "clist_2": "def",
  "branch_1": "efg"
}
for (let key in obj_) {
  if (key.includes("clist_")) {
    let num = key.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
    obj[num] = obj_[key];
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need  a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) in bracket notation for the key.

```
obj[num] = obj_[key];
//             ^^^^^
```

Then you could use `startsWith` instead of `includes` for checking the starting part of a string.

```js
var obj = {};
var obj_ = {
  "clist_1": "abc",
  "clist_2": "def",
  "branch_1": "efg"
}
for (let key in obj_) {
  if (key.startsWith("clist_")) {
    let num = key.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
    obj[num] = obj_[key];
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative chain way:

```
var obj = {};
var obj_ = {
  "clist_1": "abc",
  "clist_2": "def",
  "branch_1": "efg"
};

Object.keys(obj_)
    .map(key=>key.replace(/^\D+/g, ''))
    .map(key=>obj[key]=obj_[key]);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const obj_ = {"clist_1": "abc","clist_2": "def","branch_1": "efg"};
const obj = Object.keys(obj_)
  .filter(k => k.startsWith('clist_'))
  .reduce((a, c) => (a[c.match(/\d+/g)] = obj_[c], a), {});
  
console.log(obj);
```